# RPM build not taking if syntax in %file

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

`if ! /usr/bin/getent passwd sgate>/dev/null; then
  %define bindir /home/sgate/elasticsearch 
elif ! /usr/bin/getent passwd rgate>/dev/null; then
  %define bindir /home/rgate/elasticsearch
fi`

RPM build errors:

```
File must begin with "/": if  
File must begin with "/": !  
Two files on one line: /usr/bin/getent
File must begin with "/": passwd
Two files on one line: /usr/bin/getent
File must begin with "/": sgate>/dev/null;
Two files on one line: /usr/bin/getent
File must begin with "/": the
File not found: /root/ES_RPM/ElasticSearchRPM/BUILDROOT/elasticsearch-5.2.2-1.x86_64/home/*/elasticsearch  
File must begin with "/": elif  
File must begin with "/": !
Two files on one line: /usr/bin/getent
File must begin with "/": passwd
Two files on one line: /usr/bin/getent
File must begin with "/": rgate>/dev/null;
Two files on one line: /usr/bin/getent
File must begin with "/": then
File not found: /root/ES_RPM/ElasticSearchRPM/BUILDROOT/elasticsearch-5.2.2-1.x86_64/home/*/elasticsearch
File must begin with "/": fi
```

I am getting this error while running RPM. Where am I going wrong with this if logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use shell script in `%files` section. You can use macros, e.g.:

```
%if
...
%endif
```

But those macros conditionals are evaluated during build time and not during installation.

Comment: Yes, but they are trying to base the conditional on a user existing, which would only be known at install time, not build time, which is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

The `%define`s that you have there are not doing that you think; they are defining things and then leaving behind invalid shell code. You are probably going to need a wrapper shell or `Makefile` that calls `rpmbuild` with a definition of "`mybindir`" on the command line, *e.g.* `rpmbuild --define="mybindir /home/rgate/elasticsearch"`

**Having re-read the question**, what you are trying to do seems to be an install-time thing anyway, which you cannot decide on-the-fly like that. I would say install your stuff in a standard location, *e.g.* `/usr/share/yourpackage`, and then in the `%post` set a symlink to it in the proper user's home directory. In `%post` you are allowed to script things to do what you were expecting.